# Iron in Hot Water Heater

Tags: hot-water

My water has a lot of iron in it so I have a water softener to take care of that. The problem is I forgot to check it and it ran out of salt.

The majority of my house is fine (I have to better clean my toilet tanks still), but my hot water heater appears to be giving out brown water now. I am in the middle of draining it now so that I can flush it, but I am wondering if there is anything else I should do to care of this? Is solving this problem something for a professional or do I just need to keep flushing it out until the problem is solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flushing the water heater did the trick.